# What does it mean if I am getting the same AUC and AUROC value in a CNN?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc, auc

I am running a Convolutional Neural Network. After it finishes running, I use some metrics to evaluate the performance of the model. 2 of the metrics are the auc and roc_auc_score from sklearn

**AUC function**: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html?highlight=auc#sklearn.metrics.auc

**AUROC function**: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score

The code I am using is the following:

```
print(pred)
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(true_classes, pred, pos_label=1)
print("-----AUC-----")
print(metrics.auc(fpr, tpr))
print("----ROC AUC-----")
print(metrics.roc_auc_score(true_classes, pred))
```

Where true_classes is a table which is of the form : [0 1 0 1 1 0] where 1 is the positive label and 0 the negative.

And pred is the predictions of the model:

```
prediction = classifier.predict(test_final)
prediction1 = []
predictions = []
for preds in prediction:
    prediction1.append(preds[0])

pred = prediction1
```

However I am getting the same AUC and ROC AUC value no matter how many times I run the test (What I mean by that is that AUC and ROC AUC values in each test are the same. Not that they remain the same on all the tests. For example for test 1 I get AUC = 0.987 and ROC_AUC = 0.987 and for test 2 I get AUC = 0.95 and ROC_AUC = 0.95) . Am I doing something wrong? Or is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation linked, `metrics.auc` is a general case method to calculate area under a curve from points of that curve.

`metrics.roc_auc_score` is a specific case method used to calculate Area Under Curve for ROC curve.

You would not expect to see different results if you're using the same data to calculate both, as `metrics.roc_auc_score` will do the same thing as `metrics.auc` and, most likely, use the `metrics.auc` method itself, under the hood (i.e. use the general method for the specific task of calculating Area under ROC curve).

Comment: Oh I get it. I was confused and I thought they were calculating different things. Thank you!